# How to customize a visualization by adding more plots in one picture?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataset like this:

```
EmployeeID    BenefitsType    Status    YearsInJob
000001          M              A            3.1
000002          O              T            2.9
000003          N              A            5.1
000004          B              A            0.9
```

I would like to plot the data as the YearInJob distribution based on different categories. 
For example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
sns.distplot(wk[wk.Benefits=="M"]['Years In Job'], color = "blue", bins=20)
sns.distplot(wk[wk.Benefits=="O"]['Years In Job'], color = "green", bins=20)
sns.distplot(wk[wk.Benefits=="N"]['Years In Job'], color = "red", bins=20)
sns.distplot(wk[wk.Benefits=="B"]['Years In Job'], color = "orange", bins=20)
plt.legend(labels=['Medical','Offset','N','Both'])
```

But the above codes consider all the employees. Is there a way to distinguish the status? Like the distribution for Still Active and Terminated employees? And how to add it in the code?

I tried

```
sns.distplot(wk[wk.Benefits=="M"]['Years In Job'], hue = "Status", color = "blue", bins=20)
```

But it turned out to be an error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distplot` cannot automatically split your dataset using the `hue=` argument, therefore, you have to filter your dataframe however you see fit in the call to `distplot`.

e.g.:

```
sns.distplot(wk[(wk.Benefits=="M")&(wk.Status=="A")]['Years In Job'], color = "blue", bins=20)
sns.distplot(wk[(wk.Benefits=="M")&(wk.Status=="T")]['Years In Job'], color = "red", bins=20)
```